# where to find "package com.rim.samples.docs.notifications;"

Tags: blackberry

i a developing blackberry aplication using eclipse can any one tell where to find the following library

package com.rim.samples.docs.notifications;

i have downloaded it from blackberry site but i dont know how to use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

com.rim.samples.docs namespace is common for samples BlackBerry Application Developer Guide.

On the other hand, "[package](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_package_(programming))" token defines the packege namespace, not the import.

If you have downloaded code and post it to namespace with other name, you may have trouble to compile it. Resolve it in two ways:
1. if your code file is placed directly in project src folder, simply remove

```
package com.rim.samples.docs.notifications;
```

from code, this will set namespace to default.
2. in project src folder create folder "com\rim\samples\docs\notifications" and move file to folder "notifications".